# How to always append a class method to a chained method call

Tags: ruby, inheritance, method-chaining

Let's cay you have a class `Class` with N class methods methods that can be chained (thing of DB Model):

```rb
class Class
  def self.foo(a)
    @a = a
    self
  end

  ...
end
```

So it can be called like `Class.foo(a).bar(b)` etc.

Now, you have a child class `ChildClass` and you wan't it to always add another chained method in the end:

```rb
class ChildClass < Class
  def self.buzz(r)
    @r = r
    self
  end
end
```

So that

`ChildClass.foo(a).bar(b)`

would always actually be

`ChildClass.foo(a).bar(b).buzz(r)`

Comment: Why `ChildClass.foo(a).bar(b).buzz(r)` and not `ChildClass.foo(a).buzz(x).bar(b).buzz(r)`. What if just `ChildClass.foo(a)` is called? Should is return `ChildClass.foo(a)` or `ChildClass.foo(a).buzz(r)`? And what is `r`?

Comment: Not sure I understand your first question. Methods' and var\args' names are purely random and only there for convenience, the number of chained methods can vary. Regardless of how many methods are called in a chain (0 to infinity) the `buzz` method should be called. So if none is called - we are calling just `buzz`. If only `foo` is called we append `buzz`. How does it metter what is `r`? Let's say it is a Hash.

Comment: My question is, how can calling `ChildClass.foo(a).bar(b)` be equal to `ChildClass.foo(a).bar(b).buzz(r)` if there is a required argument without a default value? What is the argument provided to `buzz` on `ChildClass.foo(a).bar(b)`? Can it be inferred from the class, or one of the other methods called?

Comment: You can assume that Class and ChildClass are database models and that each of the chained methods return some form of a `dataset` object (but not an actual data). You can replace `foo`, `bar` and `buzz` with `select`, `where` and `order`. Their arguments are objects that will be passed down to the `dataset` object.

Comment: are you talking about something similar to how active record automatically evaluates your query at the end of the method chain?

Comment: @maxpleaner Judging from this qestion (and the answer) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332404/how-to-detect-the-end-of-a-method-chain-in-ruby I am (more or less at least). But the given answer as I understand it relies no the fact that chained method will always return an object that will have methods unavailable for an actuall data object (Array fro example). Which can be false.

Comment: Do you know how this object will be used? Is there a method which will always be called with this object, either as the receiver or as an argument?

Comment: It is not possible for ruby to _just know_ when you have reached the end of a method chain. There are hacks to get around this, such as how ActiveRecord defines `each` and `inspect` to actually evaluate the query. It's simpler to be explicit. You can define a method like `resolve`/`evaluate` which has to be manually called at the end of the chain. Or you can use some sort of block, e.g. `MyClass.send_query { <build the query in here> }`. I am happy to make an answer showing these examples but I'm not sure it's what you want.

Comment: Yeah, I've already decided I'd rather use some sort of proxy-builder and then just append whatever I have to. Thank!